# jquery-ui slider bounded to select list using numbers greater then 100 strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Probably most stupid question ever, but it is really annoying, the code compiles well and work great with range numbers 0 to 100, however, I cannot figure out why my slider control stop working when I use numbers greater than 100 ... I'm using simple jquery-ui [sample](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms)

and all looks good, but soon as change numbers greater then 100 (due to our requirements we want to use it for years), the select list stop changing the dates and slider doesn't move ... Does it support numbers greater then 100 or there is some limitations ?! js code I'm using:

```
$(function() {
var select = $( "#minbeds" );
var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
  min: 100,
  max: 1000,
  step: 100,
  range: "min",
create: function( event, ui ) {
  setSliderTicks(event.target);
},
  value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
  }
});
$( "#minbeds" ).change(function() {
  slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
});
});


function setSliderTicks(el) {
var $slider =  $(el);
var max =  $slider.slider("option", "max");    
var min =  $slider.slider("option", "min");    
var spacing =  100 / (max - min);

$slider.find('.ui-slider-tick-mark').remove();
for (var i = 0; i < max-min ; i++) {
    $('<span class="ui-slider-tick-mark"></span>').css('left', (spacing * i) +  '%').appendTo($slider); 
 }
 }
```

and here is HTML:

```
<form id="reservation">
<select name="minbeds" id="minbeds">
<option>100</option>
<option>200</option>
<option>300</option>
<option>400</option>
<option>500</option>
<option>600</option>
<option>700</option>
<option>800</option>
<option>900</option>
<option>1000</option>
</select>
</form>
```

And some CSS styles for tick-marks:

```
.ui-slider-tick-mark{
display:inline-block;
width:2px;
background:grey;
height:16px;
position:absolute;
top:-1px;
}
```

Can anyone please let me know, what is wrong with it, and in case if there are some limitations, can anyone recommend me some other library to use (open source), with the same functionality, taking input from html (select list) and with tick-marks/labels available ?! Any help appreciated ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you simply copy pasted the example and expect it to work without understanding how it works even though you have a different requirement.

The demo is using `selectedIndex` property directly because the values are ranging from 1-6 and the slider steps by one. Your values and steps are different so if you want to find the option to select by index, you should divide the slider value by step value which is 100 and subtract 1 (since the options index is 0 based). Similarly if you want to set the slider value based on selected option index, you should increment it by 1 and multiply by 100.

Instead of doing all that you can simply use the selected options value and slider value directly like:

```js
$(function() {
  var select = $("#minbeds");
  var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    step: 100,
    range: "min",
    value: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      select.val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#minbeds").change(function() {
    slider.slider("value", this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form id="reservation">
  <select name="minbeds" id="minbeds">
    <option>100</option>
    <option>200</option>
    <option>300</option>
    <option>400</option>
    <option>500</option>
    <option>600</option>
    <option>700</option>
    <option>800</option>
    <option>900</option>
    <option>1000</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks T J, works as a charm ! Yes, I've missed that bit with the values. Simply because tested so many other libraries for the last couple of days, and brains stopped working lol And I definitely like the 'short' version instead of writing all these lines. Thanks again !!